# DATA partition gets mounted as DATA1, breaking links and bookmarks

Tags: kubuntu

Since some struggle trying unsuccessfully to update PyCharm, I ended up uninstalling it and reinstalling it manually from tar.gz. Since then my DATA partition gets mounted as DATA1 (breaking all my links and bookmarks to contained folders and files).

When trying to enter a folder, e.g. using a bookmark, I get the following error in my file browser (username redacted as `<username>`).

```
Could not enter folder /media/<username>/DATA/<folder>.
```

The DATA partition (now DATA1) is mounted during startup using an autostart script:

```
#!/bin/bash
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda4
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently an improper shutdown had prevented a proper umount, so a folder named DATA had remained in `/media/$USER/`. Because that was still there during the next boot, the DATA partition was instead mounted under `/media/$USER/DATA1`.
Deleting the remnant folder DATA using root privileges solved the problem. After a reboot the partition could correctly be mounted at DATA again.